# Can Rocksmith be played with Rock Band's Squier Stratocaster?

Tags: rocksmith

Earlier this year I got the Squier Stratocaster for Rock Band 3, which can also be used as a regular electric guitar.

[image]

In Rocksmith rather than using plastic guitars, you're supposed to connect an actual electric guitar to play. **So know I want to know whether I can play Rocksmith with Rock Band's Squier Stratocaster?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rocksmith should work with any guitar that has a 1/4-inch jack and a pickup.

I just tested this with my Rock Band 3 Squier and it's working fine. You will need to just use the cable that comes with Rocksmith since the game does not require a special adapter like Rock Band does.